# How to enable Rails.cache session object for Rails app during tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, minitest

I have a multi-step intake form.

I store the data from each step in a Rails.cache object using the session.id as the key.

```
def initialize_cache
  Rails.cache.fetch(session.id) { Hash.new }
end

def add_params_to_cache
  attrs = Rails.cache.read(session.id).merge(user_profile_params)
  Rails.cache.write(session.id, attrs)
end
```

This works in development mode.

However, my tests fail because the session.id is nil.

I have enabled caching in the test.rb environment file:

```
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.cache_store = :memory_store
```

However, I still get nil for session.id.

The only poor solution I have found is to use the following method in the controllers:

```
    def session_id
  @session_id ||= Rails.env.test? ? :test : session.id
end
```

Is there a way to get the session object id during rails tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only get `session.id` when you store something in session, otherwise it's  `nil`. On the first request there is nothing stored in session yet. After your controller action is done, rails stores `_csrf_token` and so `session_id` is stored as well. Just take out:

```rb
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

from you layout and `session.id` will never be initialized (unless you have something else updating session).

Session id is [nothing](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.4/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb#L26) special but you should probably create your own key for this purpose:

```rb
# it's what session id is anyway
session[:cache_id] ||= SecureRandom.hex(16)
```

---

You can also save something into session and `id` will initialize:

```rb
# assuming there is no session
cookies.clear

session.id #=> nil

# any one of these will initialize session id
session.update({})
session.send(:load!)
session[:touch] = "poke"
# or this
session.destroy
session.clear

session.id #=> "cc3363adc0831258d3173f207a62dcae"
```

---

As far as the test is concerned, it's just showing you `session.id` is not a reliable source for your cache id. Fix it in the controller from the start.

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    p "this does not initialize session.id"
    p Rails.cache.fetch(session.id) { Hash.new }
    p session.id # still nil
    p
    p "this will initialize session"
    p session.update({}) # or any other way mentioned above
    p Rails.cache.fetch(session.id) { Hash.new }
    p session.id
  end
end
```

```bash
$ bin/rails test test/controllers/home_controller_test.rb
Running 1 tests in a single process (parallelization threshold is 50)
Run options: --seed 48575

# Running:

"this does not initialize session.id"
{}
nil
"this will initialize session"
{"session_id"=>"39c1ee00e1e9214250d0bb6cfbfa68dc"}
{}
"39c1ee00e1e9214250d0bb6cfbfa68dc"
.

Finished in 0.294108s, 3.4001 runs/s, 3.4001 assertions/s.
1 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

This is like visiting the page for the very first time. Try in incognito window, `session.id` will be `nil`, but only the first visit. In a test it's always the first visit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Alex.  When I run this in dev I initialize the session.id with an empty hash (see my answer). I do have a session id at this point. However, when I run my tests which also call the initialize method the session.id is nil.  That is why I have had to add the Rails.env.test? ? :test : session.id which I would prefer  to not.  So my question remains why when I run my tests do I not have a session.id value?

Comment: @chell see update. hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: thank you for the making that so much clearer. I have added the session.update({}).to_h to initialize the session and it works.